# Erratic scrollbar using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/igor_g/ksjkpg0t/16/

My intention is to build a scrollbar on a strip of colors. The colors are taken from the text it is supposed to scroll. Basically, the strip is an overview of all the colors that are used in the text fonts. The text is generated dynamically and can be very large and very small. My intention is to make the scroller's size proportional and at the same time scroll properly. I have tried various combinations using jquery but I just can not seem to get the scroller to work the way I want. Sometimes, the scroller doesnt seem to point to the right text passage. How can this be fixed?

The jquery code is as follows:

```
///  here is our plugin declaration
(function ( $ ) {



    $.fn.colorScroller = function( options ) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            replaceBlack: 'rgb(83, 84, 72)',
            colorScrollClass: "color-map",
            overlayClass: "overlay",
            scrollSectionClass: "mapSection",
            coloredTextClass: "passage"
        }, options );


      // assign this(the selector that is calling this function) to container
      var container = this;
      // getting the height of container
      var containerHeight = container.outerHeight(true);
      // creating overlay scrolling element
      var $overlay = $('<div class="'+settings.overlayClass+'" ></div>')
      //creating container for colored parts
      var $colorScroll=$('<div class="'+settings.colorScrollClass+'" ></div>')
      // appending colormap element after container in DOM
      container.after($colorScroll);
      // approximate total height of browser vertical scroll buttons
      var browserScrollButtons = 26;
      // setting height of colorscroll element to the height of container
      $colorScroll.outerHeight(container.outerHeight()-browserScrollButtons );

      var scrollerHandleMin = 31



      // here we are calculating the total height of text elements of container
      var totalHeight = 0;
      container.children('.'+ settings.coloredTextClass).each(function(){
        totalHeight = totalHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
      });

      // calculate height of  text empty elements like br or <p></p>
      var emptyHeight = 0;
      container.children().not('.'+ settings.coloredTextClass).each(function(){
        emptyHeight = emptyHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
      });


      // here we are calculating the ratio b/n total height of children of container and the height of color-scroll element   
      var ratio = totalHeight/$colorScroll.outerHeight();
      // here we create a jquery object containing of small divs which will be colored, and associated with each passage div in container
      var $mini = $('.'+settings.coloredTextClass, container).map(function(){ 
        // getting the height of passage, setting the height of small div element by dividing by ratio
        var heightPassage=$(this).outerHeight(true)/ratio+'px';
        // getting the color of passage
        var colorPassage=$(this).css('color');
        // color change if color is black
        if (colorPassage=='rgb(0, 0, 0)')
          colorPassage = settings.replaceBlack;

        var elem = $('<div class="'+settings.scrollSectionClass+'" style="height:'+heightPassage+'; background-color:'+colorPassage+'" ></div>').get(0)
        // returning a jquery object element with class, height and color associated according to previous calculations
        return  elem
      });

      // get approximate height of browser scroll bar  handle
      var browserScrollBarHeight = (containerHeight*(containerHeight-browserScrollButtons ))/(totalHeight + emptyHeight ) 
      browserScrollBarHeight = browserScrollBarHeight >  scrollerHandleMin ? browserScrollBarHeight : scrollerHandleMin

      // set overlay scroller height to browser scroll handle height
      $overlay.outerHeight(browserScrollBarHeight);
      var overlayHeight = $overlay.outerHeight();

      // appending the minified elements into colorscroll element 
      $($mini).appendTo($colorScroll);

      // appending overlay element into color-scroll element
      $colorScroll.append($overlay);

      // getting top position of container related to document top
      var colorScrollTop = $colorScroll.offset().top+1+parseInt($colorScroll.css('margin-top').replace('px', ''))

      // getting multiple to create algorithm for converting top positions
      var k = (totalHeight + emptyHeight - containerHeight)/($colorScroll.innerHeight()-overlayHeight)


      // attaching draggable to overlay scrolling element, so that it can be moved along color scroll element
      $overlay.draggable({ 
        // constrain movement to color-scroll element only
        containment: "."+settings.colorScrollClass,

        // what to do when overlay is dragged
        drag: function() {
          // getting top position of overlay related to document top
          var top = $(this).offset().top;
          container.animate({
            // scroll container vertically to the point of overlay top (related to color-scroll element ) associated with text in container
            scrollTop: (top-colorScrollTop)*k +'px'
          }, 2)
        },


      });


      /// when mouse on color-scroller unbind container scroll and enble draggable
      /// when mouse leaves color-scroller bind container scroll and disable draggable
        $colorScroll
          .mouseenter(function() {
            $overlay.draggable('enable')
            container.off('scroll',  scrollText) 
          })
          .mouseleave(function() {
            $overlay.draggable('disable')
            container.on('scroll',  scrollText) 
          });


      // function triggered when container scrolled, basically scroll the overlay 
      function  scrollText(){
              $overlay.animate({
                top: container.scrollTop()/k + 'px'
              }, 1)
       }
      container.on('scroll',  scrollText)    

      // when the color-scroll element is clicked
      $colorScroll.on('click',function(e){
        // calculate the position of click related to color-scroll itself
        var topPosition = e.pageY-$(this).offset().top;
        // and move overlay top to that position  
        $overlay.animate({
          top: topPosition+'px'
        }, 200)
        // and scroll container to text associated with overlay top
        container.animate({
          scrollTop: (topPosition+overlayHeight)*ratio-containerHeight+'px'
        }, 10)
      })



      return container;

    };

}( jQuery ));

///  end plugin 

$(document).ready(function() {
  var passes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

  for (var i in passes) {
    col = document.getElementById('pass' + i).style.color;
    var element = document.createElement("section");
    element.style.background = col;

    document.getElementById("left").appendChild(element);
  }
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = 'canvas';
  canvas.style = 'height:700px;width:50px;';

///   here we init plugin function
  $('#document_content').colorScroller({replaceBlack: 'rgb(0,0,0)'});
   /// the other option with defaults are : 
//         colorScrollClass: "color-map", css class of colored scrollbar
//         overlayClass: "overlay",       css class of the custom scrollbar
//         scrollSectionClass: "mapSection",  css class of the small colored sections in colored scroll bar
//         coloredTextClass: "passage"     css class of the original text part
/// 

});
```